# Change displayed text returned by google Autocomplete API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

Currently I'm using the google autocomplete to enable users to search for cities. When typing `Ber` it shows up the following:

[image: screen while typing]

which is perfectly fine.

When selecting an element, e.g. the first one, the textbox-value switches to `Berlin, Deutschland` as it can be seen here:

[image: screen while selecting]

When hitting enter or clicking the element, the text will stay the same:

[image: screen after selection]

What I want is to only show the city's name `Berlin` in the textbox without the nation at the end.
Is there any specific event I should bind to so I could crop the nation before it will be set in the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

The 'place_changed' event is the one you should be listening for

Comment: Specifically on `place_changed` use `getPlace().name`.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#get_place_information